# How do I parse a string of numbers into a array of integers?

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing, c99

I have been struggling with this for a while and figured I might as well ask for help instead of banging my head harder into a wall.

So let's say you have the string `"10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2"`
and you want to go through it, take out the numbers one by one and add it to an array of integers to use.

I have prototyped A LOT and keep making more work for myself than is necessary. At first I was using `strtok()` but then people said that was deprecated and it would be easier to use `strsep()`

How would I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My function seems to always return an int array full of zeros. Why is this?

```
int *parse_line(char *line){
    char sNumArray[MAX];
    strcpy(sNumArray, line);
    char *tokens = NULL;
    int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);
    tokens = strtok(sNumArray, " ");
    for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        numbers[i] = atoi(tokens);
        printf("%d \n", atoi(tokens));
        tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (tokens == NULL)
            break;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

These are my variables I define in the main and call my function with...

```
int *skyline;
skyline = parse_line(line);
for (int j = 0; j < 100 ; ++j) {
    printf("%d \n", skyline[j]);
}
```

Comment: `strsep` is not standard C; `strtok` is

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried, and any errors you're getting? I also suggest using `strtok` over `strsep`, as it's more widely used, and is of course standard C. In fact, you should be able to find a pretty simple tutorial for this online with `strtok`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

int *parse_line(char *line, int *numInts) {
    char sNumArray[MAX];
    strcpy(sNumArray, line);
    int *numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);
    char *tokens = strtok(sNumArray, " ");
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        numbers[i] = atoi(tokens);
        tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (tokens == NULL) {
            *numInts = i+1;
            break;
        }       
    }

    return numbers;
}

int main() {
    char *line = "10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2";
    int numIntsExtracted = 0;
    int *skyline = parse_line(line, &numIntsExtracted);

    for (int j = 0; j < numIntsExtracted; ++j) {
        printf("%d \n", skyline[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output I'm getting after running it.

```
10
10
10
4
4
4
9
9
9
2
```

Comment: Actually, I am having issues with this. When I print the int array is full of 0's I will update my code above

Comment: This fails then the first `tokens == NULL`.  Suggest `for(int i = 0; tokens; i++) {` --> `for(int i = 0; ; i++) {` and drop the `if (tokens == NULL)
            break;`

Comment: @Jak Its working except you don't see it because you are printing all 100 elements of skyline instead of the exact number you extracted.
You need to store somewhere the exact number of integers you extracted. Depending on your needs you could store this in a global variable or pass it via output variable to parse_line.

Comment: @driftwood I will try this and get back to you. Thank you for all your help

Comment: @driftwood I am still unable to get it to work could you clarify more?

Comment: @Jak I updated the code to be more like yours. If this works correctly for you please give up vote and/or accept as answer. If not, let me know and I answer any questions you have... thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have three primary options (1) use `strtol` in the manner it was intended, using the `*endptr` parameter to advance the current read position within the string to one past the last digit converted, or (2) pass to `sscanf` utilizing the `"%n"` specifier to report the number of characters used in the conversion to `int` (or whatever type) and using that value to advance the read position in the same manner; or (3) tokenizing the string with `strtok` and then using `strtol` (as `atoi` should not be used as it provides absolutely zero error checking). There really isn't any need to use both `strtok` and `strtol` as `strtol` already provides a way to advance past the digits converted. You are essentially duplicating what has already by done by `strtol` by using a call to `strtok` -- but it is a valid way to go.

For instance using `strtol` you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for strtol */
#include <string.h>     /* for strncpy */
#include <errno.h>      /* for errno */

#define MAXC 1024   /* constant - max chars in line */

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC] = "";    /* str to hold line, initialized all zero */

    while (fgets (str, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* read each line of input */
        char *p = str,      /* pointer for strtol */
            *endptr = NULL; /* end pointer for strtol */

        while (*p) {    /* work down str parsing integer or hex values */
            long val = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);  /* convert from p */

            /* validate conversion */
            if (p != endptr) {  /* were digits converted? */
                if (!errno) {   /* if errno 0, successful conversion */
                    char ascii[MAXC] = "";  /* for string converted */

                    strncpy (ascii, p, endptr - p); /* copy to ascii */
                    ascii[endptr-p] = 0;    /* nul-terminate ascii */

                    /* test whether string begins "0x" or "0X", output */
                    if (*p == '0' && (*(p + 1) == 'x' || *(p + 1) == 'X'))
                        printf ("hex conversion:  %-10s %10lu  0x%lx\n",
                                ascii, val, val);
                    else
                        printf ("int conversion:  %-10s % ld\n",
                                ascii, val);
                }
                p = endptr; /* advance p to 1-past end of converted string */
            }

            /* find start of next valid number in str, including (+/-) */
            for (; *p; p++) {
                if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')  /* positive value */
                    break;          /* explicitly signed value */
                if ((*p == '+' || *p == '-') && '0' <= *(p+1) && *(p+1) <= '9')
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2" | ./bin/fgets_strtol_any
int conversion:  10          10
int conversion:  10          10
int conversion:  10          10
int conversion:  4           4
int conversion:  4           4
int conversion:  4           4
int conversion:  9           9
int conversion:  9           9
int conversion:  9           9
int conversion:  2           2
```

or converting all the integers in a messy file, e.g.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/10intmess.txt
8572,;a -2213,;--a 6434,;
a- 16330,;a

- The Quick
Brown%3034 Fox
12346Jumps Over
A
4855,;*;Lazy 16985/,;a
Dog.
11250
1495
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_strtol_any <dat/10intmess.txt
int conversion:  8572        8572
int conversion:  -2213      -2213
int conversion:  6434        6434
int conversion:  16330       16330
int conversion:  3034        3034
int conversion:  12346       12346
int conversion:  4855        4855
int conversion:  16985       16985
int conversion:  11250       11250
int conversion:  1495        1495
```

**Using `sscanf`**

Similarly, you can use `sscanf`, but be mindful, it doesn't provide the level or degree of error handling -- meaning you can only know that it either successfully converted the text or it failed. No in between, no reporting of overflow or underflow through `errno`. But still, it along with `strtok` are other valid means of parsing integers from a line of text, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer to hold MAXC chars at a time */
    int nval = 0;           /* total number of integers found */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {

        char *p = buf;      /* pointer to line */
        int val,            /* int val parsed */
            nchars = 0;     /* number of chars read */

        /* while chars remain in buf and a valid conversion to int takes place
        * output the integer found and update p to point to the start of the
        * next digit.
        */
        while (*p) {
            if (sscanf (p, "%d%n", &val, &nchars) == 1) {
                printf (" %d", val);
                if (++nval % 10 == 0)     /* output 10 int per line */
                    putchar ('\n');
            }
            p += nchars;        /* move p nchars forward in buf */

            /* find next number in buf */
            for (; *p; p++) {
                if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') /* positive value */
                    break;
                if (*p == '-' && *(p+1) >= '0' && *(p+1) <= '9') /* negative */
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n %d integers found.\n", nval);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2" | ./bin/fgets_sscanf_int_any_ex
 10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2

 10 integers found.
```

or with messy input

```
$ echo "1, 2 buckle my shoe, 3, 4..." | ./bin/fgets_sscanf_int_any_ex
 1 2 3 4
 4 integers found.
```

Using `strtok` would simply be a "front-end" to conversion with `strtol` shown in the first example (which provides its own way to tokenizing numeric values). You simply loop over your buffer calling `strtok` with delimiters of `" \n"` (space newline) and then using `strtol` to convert the string pointed to. (here you are simply using `endptr` to validate digits were converted and ignoring its use to advance past the digits converted. Essentially, `strtok` duplicates what is already done by `strtok`, but if it makes it easier to understand, and you can live with the duplicate call, it's fine. You could do something like the following.

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        char *p = buf;  /* pointer to buf to use with strtok */
        /* 1st call using buffer, all remaining calls using NULL */
        for (p = strtok (p, " \n"); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \n")) {
            errno = 0;                          /* reset errno */
            char *endptr;                       /* end pointer */
            long tmp = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);  /* convert using long */
            if (p != endptr) {      /* validate digits converted */
                /* now validate value within range of int */
                if (!errno && INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX)
                    /* you have an integer! */
            }
            else if (tmp == 0)
                /* no digits were converted */
        }
    }
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: `for (; *p; p++) {
                if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')  /* positive value */
                    break;          /* explicitly signed value */
                if ((*p == '+' || *p == '-') && '0' <= *(p+1) && *(p+1) <= '9')
                    break;
            }` could be replaced with `} else { p++; }`in first code.

Comment: I found a space in `"%d%n"` --> `"%d %n"` nicely and quickly skips trailing spaces.  Useful when looking for `'\0'`.

Comment: Ooh, that's a nice improvement. It would also cut down on iterating over whitespace searching for the next numeric value as well. Duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the function `strtol()` for this, because if you pass it a pointer, it will return the next point to continue parsing.  There are also unsigned versions, e.g.: `strtoul()`.  They are standard since C99.  Also `strtol()` can parse hexadecimal, and handles errors somewhat better than older functions like `atoi()` (which returns 0 on error).

The important part of the code below is the result from `strtol()`.  When `next_number` is un-changed after the call, there is no more input (or an error occurred).  The variable `ptr` is used to keep track of where the parsing is up to in the string.  It's given to `strtol()`, which changes `next_number` to point to the next element, so then `ptr` jumps forward - assigned to `next_number` (past the element just parsed), and the process repeats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *number_str = "10 10 10 4 4 4 9 9 9 2";
    char *ptr;
    char *next_number;
    int   numbers[1000];
    int   number_count = 0;
    long  num;

    next_number = number_str;

    do
    {
        ptr = next_number;
        num = strtol(ptr, &next_number, 10);
        if (ptr != next_number) // found one
        {
            numbers[number_count] = (int)num;
            printf("Stored %3d into numbers[%d]\n", numbers[number_count], number_count);
            number_count += 1;
        }
    } while(ptr != next_number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Just use scanf() to get each number one by one in for or while loop.

```
for i = 0 to n
scanf(“%d”, &num);
```

Pls refer google or bing search online how it is done with many examples available.

Comment: This answer is not in C-syntax.